# What compiler does not support the style of "%#x" in printf flags?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, posix, printf

I understand %#x give the same effect of 0x%x and it meets POSIX standard. But people mention that some compilers do not support it. Is that true, any example?

Comment: C compilers are all fine with it. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a libc somewhere that wasn't.

Comment: To explain @Dave's comment, a compiler is just part of a C implementation, and not the part that implements `printf`. That's provided by the C library, which may or may not even be from the same organization that provided the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from perhaps some broken embedded-systems C libraries, the `#` modifier should be universally supported. However `%#x` and `0x%x` are not the same. They yield different results for the value 0, and the `#` modifier will always print the `x` in the same case as the hex digits (e.g. `%#x` gives `0xa` and `%#X` gives `0XA`) while using `0x%X` would allow you to have a lowercase `x` and capital hex digits (much more visually pleasing, at least to me). As such, I find the `#` modifier is rarely useful in practice.

Answer (score 2):

`%#x` is a valid conversion specification in `printf` format string in C89, C99 and C11.

Comment: This is the most relevant answer.  There are features specified by the C99 and/or C11 standards that *aren't* supported by many current compilers.  Microsoft's C compiler, in particular, has good C89/C90 support but very poor C99 support.  But `%#x` has been in the standard since the original ANSI C standard of 1989, and so (almost?) all modern C implementations should support it.

Answer (score 2):

The `#` flag character is not from POSIX, but rather the C standard (§7.21.6.1).  If a compiler or library does not support it then it is not a C compiler / standard library.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid as per `C` Specification - `7.21.6.1 The fprintf function` - point `#6`

> #
>
> The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’. For o conversion, it increases
>      the precision, if and only if necessary, to force the first digit of the result to be a
>      zero (if the value and precision are both 0, a single 0 is printed). For x (or X)
>      conversion, a nonzero result has 0x (or 0X) prefixed to it. For a, A, e, E, f, F, g,
>      and G conversions, the result of converting a floating-point number always
>      contains a decimal-point character, even if no digits follow it. (Normally, a
>      decimal-point character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit
>      follows it.) For g and G conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the
>      result. For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.